# Selenium: How can a I find the following element?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm trying to find an element in Selenium but it is not working.

How can I get the text "Invalid username and/or password" to compare with a string?

```html
<p style="color: red; padding-top: 25px">Invalid username and/or password.</p>
```

Thanks;

Comment: Please define ["but it is not working"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: How about trying smth and share a piece of code?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: Let me know if your query is resolved or you are still looking for an answer.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information. The xpath I was using is wrong. The answer resolved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of these below mentioned code.

**Method 1)**

**Using `xpath locator`**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@style='color: red; padding-top: 25px']"));
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `style` attribute of `<p>` tag.

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@style='color: red; padding-top: 25px'][text()='Invalid username and/or password.']"));
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `style` attribute of `<p>` tag along with `text` method.

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Invalid username and/or password.']"));
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `text` method along with `<p>` tag.

**Method 2)**

**Using `cssSelector`**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p[style='color: red; padding-top: 25px']"));
```

Answer (score 2):

For your HTML snippet,

```html
<p style="color: red; padding-top: 25px">Invalid username and/or password.</p>
```

You can use the following selector

```
element(by.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Invalid username and/or password.')]"));
```

This code is for Protractor. You can use the same in Java using the `By.XPATH` syntax that Java bindings for Selenium provides.